# [ROS2] ros2 command stucks without exit

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm planning to convert my code to ROS2 Galactic. So i installed on all my machines ROS2 Galactic beside Foxy.

Now I have a problem only on one PC:
After sourcing ROS2 Galactic `setup.bash` file, all ROS2 stuff was corruptet e.g.

- the command `$ ros2 node list` didn't show any entries and did not exit the command.
- Nodes can be started with `$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker` but after interrupt with `CTRL+C` the process did not finish. I have to press `CTRL+Z` to get back to the command line (see log below)

  ```
   user@towerpc:~$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
   [INFO] [1632818912.115210752] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
   [INFO] [1632818913.115177171] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
   [INFO] [1632818914.115188251] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
   [INFO] [1632818915.115207054] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 4'
   ^C[INFO] [1632818915.232758595] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
   ^Z [3]+ Stopped                 ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
  ```
- restarting daemon with `$ ros2 daemon stop` stucks without any message and do not exit.
  After a while a timeout is raised:

  ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/opt/ros/galactic/bin/ros2", line 11, in <module>
       load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')()
     File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 67, in main
       rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
     File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/command/daemon.py", line 38, in main
       return extension.main(args=args)
     File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/verb/daemon/stop.py", line 29, in main
       with DaemonNode(args) as daemon:
     File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/node/daemon.py", line 116, in __enter__
       methods = self._proxy.system.listMethods()
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1109, in __call__
       return self.__send(self.__name, args)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1450, in __request
       response = self.__transport.request(
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1153, in request
       return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1165, in single_request
       http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1278, in send_request
       self.send_content(connection, request_body)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1308, in send_content
       connection.endheaders(request_body)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
       self.send(msg)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 947, in send
       self.connect()
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 918, in connect
       self.sock = self._create_connection(
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
       raise err
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
       sock.connect(sa)
   TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
  ```

All my packages are up to date and only on this PC exists this problem. But I need this PC for Continuous Integration. This PC works on Ubuntu 20.04 (64-bit) with kernel Linux 5.11.0-36-generic. I have installed Galactic via `$ apt install ros-galactic-desktop`.

I am sourcing all ROS environments via a Bash script, so I can guarantee, that I source ROS2 always on all PCs the same way.

if someone has an idea, how can i fix this, pls let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387550/%5Bros2%5D-ros2-command-stucks-without-exit/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2021-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-28**:
Just to make sure: `ctrl+z` suspends, it does not terminate. Are you killing the processes you've suspended?

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2021-09-28**:
Yes I killed the processes after suspending.

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2021-09-28**:
found out that UFW blocked something.
with disabled UFW everything workes fine.
Which rule do I need for my UFW with default ROS2 settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Firewall `UFW` blocked the discovery of the Cyclone DDS

So disable your firewall or better, add rules for port 7400 & 7401 (default discovery ports; see [this comment](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/issues/143#issuecomment-479389361) ) to your ufw

---

Originally posted by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) with karma: 219 on 2021-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-28**:
Please note: DDS can use more ports than just the two you mention.